# Using Redemption GetMessageFromID in multithreaded scenario

Tags: multithreading, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have read an FAQ about using Redemption from multiple threads, but it is not clear to me what is "creatable Redemption object"?
We are using Redemption to get proper sent date and internet message id from sent items.
I initialize a global object from the main thread and set MAPISESSION from main thread also, this way:

```
public void Init()
{
    _rdoSession.Logon();
    _rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = ThisAddIn.Instance.Session.MAPIOBJECT;

    _storeId = ThisAddIn.Instance.Session.DefaultStore.StoreID;
}
```

Then I get items that way:

```
public RDOMail GetEmailFromServer(string entryID, string storeID = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (storeID == null)
        {
            storeID = _storeId;
        }
        return _rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(entryID, storeID, MAPI_NO_CACHE | MAPI_BEST_ACCESS);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e, "Error getting message from server with RDO");
    }

    return null;
}

public Task<RDOMail> GetEmailFromServerAsync(string entryID, string storeID = null)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetEmailFromServer(entryID, storeID));
}
```

It seems to work, but does it use shared session in this case?
And as I understand RDOMail is a COM object that gets passed to another thread (and cleared there with Marshal.ReleaseComObject). Is that ok or we better do everything in a thread where we get it?

And maybe there is an easier way to get internet message id and sent date from the server? Does it download whole e-mail (with attachments) in our implementation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no reason to call `Logon` **and** set the `MAPIOBJECT` property. Just set the MAPIOBJECT properly.

Secondly, since your code is running in a COM addin, there is no need to create a global `RDOSession` (unless you are really using it) - Outlook initializes the MAPI system for you anyway on the main thread.

Thirdly, the code running in a separate thread (`Task.Run`), needs its own `RDOSession` to initialize MAPI on that thread. For that, you will need to store `ThisAddIn.Instance.Session.MAPIOBJECT` in a separate variable in your `Init()` method called on the main thread. The code running in a separate thread will then need to create its own `RDOSession` and set is `MAPIOBJECT` property to a variable set on the main thread - this way you will not be marshalling any OOM objects between threads (which Outlook really does no like).

Comment: Thanks! And what about objects release and attachments download? Does it download attachments also when using GetMessageFromID?

Comment: No, the attachment data is only downloaded when you actually access it.